# The jQuery .ready() event and building content in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

let's say I have a simple javascript like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if(login == "1") {
      showExtMenu(); //Show the logged in user the extra menu links
  } else {
      showRegMenu(); //Show the user the regular menu
  }

});
```

showExtMenu and showRegMenu populates an empty div with some html code. My question is, will the page render before the div is populated? I'm not interested in content that appears a few miliseconds after the page has been shown to the user.

Thanks for your time

Comment: This sort of thing is best done on the server.

Comment: I know, but I'm interested in wether or not this can be done. If I have to do it server-side it's going to take a lot of rewriting :)

Comment: @cletus has a good point here.  Using JavaScript means that your "logged in" menu would be downloaded to all clients (even non-logged in), hidden links could be found by source viewers or even followed by robots - gulp.

Comment: I know, but security isn't really an issue here. I just needed to know if this was a good approach. Thanks for the comments though.

Comment: The delay will be less prominent if the menus that showExtMenu() and showRegMenu() reveal are already loaded on the client. If you are loading them in using ajax, the user experience will not be much fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page will be rendered for some time before the ready event is fired - it fires when the whole page is read, parsed and the whole DOM is constructed. If your page is large, the browser will display what it has gotten so far even if it's incomplete.

And in any case, as cletus notes in the comments, this looks like a server-side job.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a rewriting job for me.. sigh

Answer (score 0):

45 minutes into rewriting my code and I get that "This looks so much better" feeling. This is why I love stackoverflow.